# Meteor publishes even when autopublish is removed

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

I am using Meteor 1.0

I have the following code :

/lib/collections.js

```
Members = new Mongo.Collection('members');
```

/lib/router.js

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('members'); }
});

Router.route('/', {name: 'menu'});
Router.route('/member/new/', {name: 'memberNew'});
Router.route('/member/renew/', {name: 'memberRenewal'});
```

/server/publications.js

```
Meteor.publish('members', function() {
    console.log("Publishing....");
    return Members.find();
});
```

/client/templates/memberList.js

```
Template.membersList.helpers({
    listMembers: function() {
        return members.find().fetch();    >>>>>> Error line
    }
});
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: members is not defined
at Object.Template.membersList.helpers.listMembers
(http://meteorvb.dhcp.meraka.csir.co.za:3000/client/templates/membersList.js?
```

I have removed autopublish bit if I change /client/templates/memberList.js to read

```
Template.membersList.helpers({
    listMembers: function() {
        return Members.find().fetch();    
    }
});
```

Everything works.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. The error is caused by the fact that the collection is called "Members" with a capital M, but you had put "members". Then you fixed that in your code and it worked. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - i understood from thew meteor book that if you removed autopublish from Meteor that the client would not be able to access the 'Members' collection directly but had to use the subscription 'members'. Am i understanding this incorrectly?

Comment: `members` is both the collection name in the MongoDB and the name Meteor uses to determine with which client-side collection to synchronise the data you publish on the server.  But it isn't a JS object, just a name.  `Members` is the JS object with the Meteor API attached to it that allows you to search/insert/remove/etc within that collection.  Really, this is just a wrapper around a MongoDB or MiniMongo collection with an API and pub/sub logic built in.

Comment: By removing autopublish you have to manually publish your collection, which you're doing. The collection's name is "members" since that's the name you gave when you created it. However, the Javascript object that references that collection is called Members (Members = new Mongo.Collection('members');) and find() is a method on that **object**.

Comment: To clarify, the JS collection object could be `Foo` on the server and `Bar` on the client if you wanted, and would still synchronise correctly if both sides had `members` provided as the collection name attribute.  But that would be fairly silly as you'd have to remember to do `Foo.find()` on the server and `Bar.find()` on the client, which is why nobody would ever do things that way.

Comment: Thanks richsilv - I think I understand now - sorry but im a newbie to js and meteor.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a typo where you have used lowercase m instead of upper case M for Members.

```
Template.membersList.helpers({
    listMembers: function() {
        return Members.find().fetch();    >>>>>> Error line
    }
});
```

Variables are case sensitive and since the members collection was assigned to "Members" you need to refer it as "Members" elsewhere.

```
Members = new Mongo.Collection('members');
```